# Prove that $f([0,1)) = [0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a continuous function $f:[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$. Furthermore, it is given that 
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$$

Prove that $f([0,1)) = [0, \infty)$

**My thoughts**

The fact that $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$$implies that $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \infty.$$ If I could prove that $f(x)$ is a monotone strictly increasing function, I could use the intermediate value theorem (given that $f(x)$ is continuous) to prove that $f[0,1) \subset [0,\infty)$ and $f$ surjective, thus 
$f([0,1)) = [0, \infty)$.

Any help would be useful

Comment: You don't need monotonicity to apply IVT.

Comment: These limits are as $x\to 1^-.$

Comment: "If I could prove that f(x) is a monotone strictly increasing function"  You can't prove what isn't true.  It's very easy to imaging a function that fluctuates before approaching the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is bounded, that is $\exists M > 0$ such that

$$\forall x \in [0,1), 0 \leq f(x) \leq M$$

Then $$\frac1{f(x)} \geq \frac1M$$

hence $\frac1{f(x)}$ can't get arbitarily close to  $0$ which is a contradiction. Hence it must be unbounded.

Hence, given any $W >0$, $\exists y \in (0,1)$, such that $f(y)  > W$. You can then apply intermediate value theorem to prove that you can attain any value between $0$ and $f(y)$, which includes $W$. That is we can attain any positive numbers.

Also, we can't attain any negative value as $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in [0,1)$.

Remark: you can't prove that it is monotone strictly increasing as the function might fluctuate.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is basically correct, then, there are several ways to formalize it. Here is one:

You have to prove that, for any $y\in [0,\infty)$, there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. In fact, by continuity, it suffices if there exists $x$ with $f(x)=M>y$.

The definition of limit implies that, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $x$ such that $\frac{1}{f(x)}<\epsilon$, i.e. $f(x)>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{y}$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is an $m>0$ so that there is no $x$ such that $f(x) = m$.  Then for any $M > m$ there is no $y$ so that $f(y) = M$ because by the intermediate value thereom that would imply there is an $x \in [0, y]$ so that $f(x) = m$.

So if there an $m > 0$ so that there is no $x$ such that $f(x) = m$ then $f(x) < m$ for all $x \in [0, 1)$.  Thus $\frac 1{f(x)} > \frac 1m$ for all $x$. Thus the limit is not $0$.

Thus every for every $m \in [0,\infty)$ there is an $x$ so that $f(x) = m$.